# R svyglm na.exclude predict and na padding

Tags: r, na, glm, survey, predict

I'm to use predict with the svlgm function and I'm having trouble getting predict to pad out the resulting vector with NAs as I would expect (and indeed can achieve with a non-survey glm using na.exclude).

Running svyglm with na.exclude gives the following error

Warning message:
In model.matrix(glm.object) * resid(glm.object, "working") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Am I asking svyglm/predict to do something I shouldn't, or is this an error with the svyglm package? Is there a way of getting predict to produce a vector padded with NAs from a svyglm object?

Any advice/help greatly appreciated

```
library(survey)
y=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
x1=c(1,0,1,1,1,NA,2,2,2,2,1,0,NA,1,0,0,0,2,2,2)
x2=c(10,21,33,55,40,30,26,84,NA,87,20,21,23,25,NA,60,76,84,71,87)
x3=runif(20)
foo=data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3)

m1=glm(y~x1+x2, family=binomial(logit),na.action=na.exclude)
predict(m1) 


svy1 <-
  svydesign(
ids=~0,
data = foo,
weights = ~x3
  )

m2 <- svyglm(y ~ x1+x2, svy1,na.action=na.exclude)
predict(m2)
```

Comment: do you want `na.omit`?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply - na.omit doesn't pad out the resulting vector with NAs. In the example above you can see predict m1 returns 20 results, including NAs, na.omit only returns non NA values

Comment: hi `m2 <- svyglm(y ~ x1+x2, svy1,na.action=na.omit) ; predict(m2)` gives the same numbers as 
`m2 <- svyglm(y ~ x1+x2, subset( svy1 , !is.na( x1 ) & !is.na( x2 ) ) ) ; predict(m2)`  there isn't a way to predict the incomplete cases using the complete model.

Comment: Hi Anthony - thank you for the reply: I can see that subsetting the data doesn't change the results. Indeed, the long way around would be to subset the data, run the model then merge the results back into the 'full' data frame. Ideally, I'd like to be able to omit that step and I was hoping svyglm would behave in a similar way to glm and pad the results with NAs. The documentation for svyglm indicates it should behave in this way (and pad the results with NAs if na.exclude is used) - but in practice it throws an error