# Using na.exclude in svyglm in the survey package

Tags: r, predict, survey

I have a question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663568/r-svyglm-na-exclude-predict-and-na-padding) several years ago without an answer. It would seem that when fitting a model with `svyglm`, NAs are omitted, irrespective of whether `na.action` is set or not. This matters also when trying to use the `predict` function to create new columns in existing data.frames.

To reiterate the same example given in the old post:

```
library('survey')
y  = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2)
x2 = c(10, 21, 33, 55, 40, 30, 26, 84, NA, 87, 20, 21, 23, 25, NA, 60, 76, 84, 71, 87)
x3 = runif(20)
foo = data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

m1 = glm(y ~ x1 + x2, 
         family = binomial(logit), 
         na.action = na.exclude)

svy1 = svydesign(ids = ~ 0,
                 data = foo,
                 weights = ~ x3)

m2 <- svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, 
             design = svy1, 
             family = binomial(logit), 
             na.action = na.exclude)

predict(m1)
predict(m2)

foo2 = foo
foo2$x2 = runif(nrow(foo), 15, 50)
foo2$x2[c(8, 15, 19)] = NA

predict(m1, newdata = foo2)
predict(m2, newdata = foo2)
```

`predict.glm` here produces predictions that include missing values, while `predict.svyglm` does not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that `survey:::predict.svyglm` (where `predict` dispatches to) has no `na.action` argument, while `stats:::predict.glm` does. So obviously `na.action` is ignored in the former (see source code) and `NA` is removed by default.

```
> args(survey:::predict.svyglm)
function (object, newdata = NULL, total = NULL, type = c("link", 
    "response", "terms"), se.fit = (type != "terms"), vcov = FALSE, 
    ...) 
NULL

> args(stats:::predict.glm)
function (object, newdata = NULL, type = c("link", "response", 
    "terms"), se.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL, 
    na.action = na.pass, ...) 
NULL
```

You could rewrite the method by implementing `na.action` in it, e.g. this way:

```
predict.svyglm <- function(object, newdata=NULL, total=NULL, type=c("link", "response", 
                      "terms"), se.fit=(type != "terms"), vcov=FALSE, na.action = na.pass, ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (is.null(newdata)) {
    newdata <- model.frame(object$survey.design)
    na.act <- object$na.action
  } else {
    newdata <- na.action(newdata[attr(object$terms, 'term.labels')])
    na.act <- attr(newdata, 'na.action')
  }
  object$na.action <- NULL
  if (type == "terms") {
    eta <- survey:::predterms(object, se=se.fit, ...)
    if (identical(attr(na.act, 'class'), 'exclude') && !is.null(na.act)) {
      eta <- stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, eta)
    }
    return(eta)
  }
  tt <- delete.response(terms(formula(object)))
  mf <- model.frame(tt, data=newdata, xlev=object$xlevels)
  mm <- model.matrix(tt, mf, contrasts.arg=object$contrasts)
  if (!is.null(total) && attr(tt, "intercept")) {
    mm[, attr(tt, "intercept")] <- mm[, attr(tt, "intercept")] * 
      total
  }
  eta <- drop(mm %*% coef(object))
  d <- drop(object$family$mu.eta(eta))
  eta <- switch(type, link=eta, response=object$family$linkinv(eta))
  if (identical(attr(na.act, 'class'), 'exclude') && !is.null(na.act)) {
    eta <- stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, eta)
  }
  if (se.fit) {
    if (vcov) {
      vv <- mm %*% vcov(object) %*% t(mm)
      if (identical(attr(na.act, 'class'), 'exclude') && !is.null(na.act)) {
        vv <- stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, vv)
        vv <- t(stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, t(vv)))
        d <- stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, d)
      }
      attr(eta, "var") <- switch(type, link=vv, response=d * 
                                   (t(vv * d)))
    } else {
      vv <- drop(rowSums((mm %*% vcov(object)) * mm))
      if (identical(attr(na.act, 'class'), 'exclude') && !is.null(na.act)) {
        vv <- stats:::napredict.exclude(na.act, vv)
      } 
      attr(eta, "var") <- switch(type, link=vv, response=drop(d * t(vv * d)))
    }
  }
  attr(eta, "statistic") <- type
  class(eta) <- "svystat"
  eta
}
```

### Usage

```
library(survey)

svy1 <- svydesign(ids=~ 0, data=foo, weights=~ x3)

## na.omit
predict(object <- svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, design=svy1, family='binomial', na.action=na.omit),
        newdata=foo) 
#        link     SE
# 1  -2.74783 1.3374
# 2  -6.01717 2.4207
# 3  -1.50677 1.0252
# 4  -0.31968 1.4078
# 5  -1.12906 1.0833
# 6  -1.66865 1.0237
# 7   1.97841 1.5724
# 8   5.10803 1.6053
# 10  5.26990 1.6985
# 11 -2.20824 1.1194
# 12 -6.01717 2.4207
# 13 -5.90926 2.4398
# 14 -1.93845 1.0532
# 16 -3.91277 3.1713
# 17 -3.04943 3.6378
# 18  5.10803 1.6053
# 19  4.40656 1.2596
# 20  5.26990 1.6985
# Warning message:
#   In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

```
## na.exclude
predict(svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, design=svy1, family='binomial', na.action=na.exclude), 
               newdata=foo)
#     response     SE
# 1  0.0602093 0.0757
# 2  0.0024306 0.0059
# 3  0.1814174 0.1522
# 4  0.4207545 0.3431
# 5  0.2443344 0.2000
# 6  0.1586042 0.1366
# 7  0.8785111 0.1678
# 8  0.9939883 0.0096
# 9         NA     NA
# 10 0.9948822 0.0086
# 11 0.0990130 0.0999
# 12 0.0024306 0.0059
# 13 0.0027069 0.0066
# 14 0.1258188 0.1158
# 15        NA     NA
# 16 0.0195934 0.0609
# 17 0.0452420 0.1571
# 18 0.9939883 0.0096
# 19 0.9879499 0.0150
# 20 0.9948822 0.0086
# Warning message:
#   In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

```
## na.exclude in predict.svyglm

predict(svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, design=svy1, family='binomial'), 
               newdata=foo_NA, na.action=na.exclude)
#    response     SE
# 1  0.999765 0.0013
# 2  0.999995 0.0000
# 3  0.999995 0.0000
# 4  0.999995 0.0000
# 5        NA     NA
# 6  0.643391 0.5614
# 7  0.999763 0.0013
# 8        NA     NA
# 9  0.643010 0.5619
# 10 0.036086 0.0566
# 11 0.641770 0.5636
# 12 0.988457 0.0453
# 13 0.645963 0.5578
# 14 0.999754 0.0014
# 15       NA     NA
# 16 0.640123 0.5659
# 17 0.999995 0.0000
# 18 0.999759 0.0014
# 19       NA     NA
# 20 0.999760 0.0014
# 21 0.641986 0.5633
# 22 0.644476 0.5599
# 23 0.988718 0.0441
# 24 0.037487 0.0579
# 25 0.999995 0.0000
# Warning message:
#   In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
```

---

*Data:*

```
foo <- structure(list(y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), x1 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2), x2 = c(10, 21, 33, 55, 40, 30, 26, 84, 
NA, 87, 20, 21, 23, 25, NA, 60, 76, 84, 71, 87), x3 = c(0.560080145020038, 
0.260075693251565, 0.0398760288953781, 0.508186420192942, 0.496490396093577, 
0.372899192618206, 0.57026850595139, 0.968372587347403, 0.0817912963684648, 
0.722660716157407, 0.78440785780549, 0.0374867296777666, 0.201261537149549, 
0.332104755565524, 0.566964805591851, 0.010931215249002, 0.0853019708301872, 
0.46296559041366, 0.449913740158081, 0.759272540919483)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))


foo_NA <- structure(list(y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x1 = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 5L), x2 = c(0.982817197917029, 0.759544267551973, 
0.566488424083218, 0.849689718568698, NA, 0.271286614704877, 
0.828158485237509, NA, 0.240544739644974, 0.0429887960199267, 
0.140479094116017, 0.21638541505672, 0.479398564202711, 0.197410342283547, 
NA, 0.00788473873399198, 0.375489964615554, 0.514407708309591, 
NA, 0.581604002509266, 0.157905208179727, 0.359028305858374, 
0.645631878403947, 0.775823362637311, 0.563646841561422), x3 = c(0.233703398611397, 
0.0899805163498968, 0.0856120649259537, 0.305218369467184, 0.667426514672115, 
0.000238896580412984, 0.208569956943393, 0.933034127345309, 0.925644748611376, 
0.734094301005825, 0.333071983419359, 0.515063329832628, 0.743974646320567, 
0.619159240042791, 0.62624534452334, 0.217157698236406, 0.216567310970277, 
0.388945028651506, 0.942455691983923, 0.962608013767749, 0.73985527921468, 
0.73324590572156, 0.535761289997026, 0.00227296608500183, 0.608937452547252
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This works on the example provided, but for some reason, it doesn't on a similar but different example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75731170/2441565) for the example.

Comment: Nevermind, I think maybe all that was missing was passing the na.action to the model frame, so changing mf <- model.frame(tt, data=newdata, xlev=object$xlevels) to mf <- model.frame(tt, data=newdata, xlev=object$xlevels, na.action = na.act). Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but this still doesn't work on the example below.

Comment: @tcam Works fine for me, use a fresh R session.

Comment: How odd, with a fresh R session the last line in the example (predicting values on new data.frame foo2) actually now is 96 elements long rather than 97 that it was before, or the 100 it should be.

Comment: Can you confirm that the new function does work as expected in the example given below (specifically when predicting values with newdata = foo2)? Because it doesn't here, and would rather not go ahead with something that might potentially be wrong.

Comment: I think what's going wrong is that if newdata is provided, it becomes NULL on this line     newdata <- na.action(newdata[attr(object$terms, 'term.labels')]), and then it proceeds as if newdata was never provided.

Answer (score 0):

`svyglm` behaves the same way as `glm` with `na.exclude` (since version 4.1-1): like `glm` it omits observations with `NA`s but reinserts the `NA`s into residuals. In your example

```
> length(resid(m1))
[1] 20
> length(resid(m2))
[1] 20
> length(fitted(m1))
[1] 20
> length(fitted(m2))
[1] 20
```

`predict.svyglm` doesn't support `na.exclude` and will only give you predictions when you actually supply the data.  The reason is that `predict.svyglm` has the ability to compute a variance-covariance matrix of the predictions, which requires that they all exist.

If you wrote to the maintainer and asked for `predict.svyglm` to support `na.exclude` when the  covariance matrix isn't being requested, he might well add that feature.

Comment: Emailed maintainer on 02/02, no response yet. He may build on my `predict` if he finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your responses. [@jay.sf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574038/jay-sf) I thought your amended function was what I needed; it worked fine on the example I provided. However, I now realise that it doesn't seem to produce the expected output on a different but similar example. With na.exclude, I would expect predicted values to be of the same length as the data provided, but here, they are not. Any idea why?

```
y  = sample(c(0, 1), size = 100, replace = T)
x1 = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = T)
x2 = runif(100)
x2[5] = NA
x3 = runif(100)
foo = data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

m1 = glm(y ~ x1 + x2, 
         family = 'binomial', 
         na.action = na.exclude)

svy = svydesign(ids = ~ 0,
                data = foo,
                weights = ~ x3)

m2 = svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, 
            design = svy, 
            family = 'binomial')

m3 = svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, 
            design = svy, 
            na.action = na.exclude,
            family = 'binomial')

# This works as expected:
length(predict(m1))
# [1] 100
length(predict(m2))
# [1] 99
length(predict(m3))
# [1] 100

foo2 = foo
foo2$x2[c(8, 15, 19)] = NA

# This doesn't:
length(predict(m1, newdata = foo2))
# [1] 100
length(predict(m2, newdata = foo2))
# [1] 96
length(predict(m3, newdata = foo2))
# [1] 97
```

EDIT: Only a small modification to @jay.sf's function fixed this. Just change

```
  mf = model.frame(tt, data = newdata, xlev = object$xlevels)
```

to

```
  mf = model.frame(tt, data = newdata, xlev = object$xlevels, na.action = na.act)
```

Comment: This is obviously wrong.